# Can structured streaming control the speed of data arrival?

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

For example, I have a file size of 100MB, and I use structured streaming to handle it. I want to read in 10MB each time, then output the result, read in 10MB again, and then process it. But structured streaming seems to read 100MB directly into the processing and wait for new data to process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structured streaming now support Rate Source, and using rowsPerSecond can get certain number of data you want.